# Json schema date-time validation including specific dates

Tags: validation, datetime, format, jsonschema

I would like to know if it is possbile to specify in a json schema that a string is of format date-time **and** is restricted to a specific interval.

In my case, I need to validate that the year of the submitted date is within the interval 2006 to 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next version of the standard (v5) has the [proposed keywords `formatMaximum`/`formatMinimum`](https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/formatMinimum-%28v5-proposal%29) which would do *exactly* what you wanted, in an elegant way: they combine with `format` to provide format-specific min/max.

Currently (with v4), your only option is to create a hack using `pattern` (e.g. `^20(0[6-9]|1[0-2])`).  However, this is completely horrible, and best avoided if possible.

Comment: Hi, do you know when will be available to use formatMaximum/formatMinimum? I've tried some examples (here https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/blob/master/KEYWORDS.md#formatmaximum--formatminimum-and-exclusiveformatmaximum--exclusiveformatminimum-v5-proposal), but output is always as valid json, even if date is out of range. Also I've enabled strictProperties flag. Do you know if I miss something?

Comment: Can you update your answer please? The link is dead and the standard is at v7. Is this now implemented?

Comment: Maybe use regexp keyword - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45888524/empty-values-validation-in-json-schema-using-ajv/62971172#62971172